# error:$("#menu ul.menu").lavalamp is not a function

Tags: jquery, css

dear all..i have a problem.
at firebug show:
    $("#menu ul.menu").lavaLamp is not a function at menu.js

the hover at menu not show.
this problem show after i put this:

```
<style type="text/css">
                * { margin:0 auto;
                    padding:0;
                    }
                body{
                                weigth:800px;
                                overflow:auto;
                                }
                div#menu {
                                margin:40px 0 0 95px;
                                text-align:center;
                                position:absolute;
                                }
                div#menu span {
                                font-size:22px;
                                padding-left:14px;
                                }
                div#copyright {

                                font:11px 'Trebuchet MS';
                                color:#fff;
                                text-align:center;
                                clear:left;
                                position:absolute;
                                top:546px;
                                width:560px;
                                }
                div#copyright a { color:#fff; }
                div#copyright a:hover { color:#fff; }
        </style>

 <div id="menu">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="index1.php" class="parent"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Inspection</span></a>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="inspection_report1.php#tabs-1"><span>Inspection Report</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="inspection_report1.php#tabs-2"><span>Input Data</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Statistics</span></a>
                    <div>
                            <ul>
                                    <li><a href="monitoring.php"><span>Monitor</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
            </li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Contacts</span></a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question...you posted a JavaScript error  (not including the plugin it looks like) but included all your CSS code.  Can you remove the CSS and add your `<script>` tag includes?

Comment: which script that you want to see?

Comment: CSS changes wouldn't cause a Javascript error.  However added `<style>` tags may if your code is sensitive to DOM elements.  Perhaps combining all the CSS into one `<style>` tag would get your code working again.

Comment: What is this "lavalamp" thing? Where is that supposed to come from?

Comment: @all:that error message show after i have put some script like at my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to fix your html to work with lavalamp.

Request you to read the link well and I hope you will discover this,
http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/

Thanks

Comment: i have downloaded my menubar using apycom.com..
how to make it have a compatible lavalamp?please help.

Comment: the above link provides a good explanation on lavalamp and also has demo. Follow please.

Answer (score 0):

the simple answer is type like this:

```
<link type="text/css" href="menu bar/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="menu bar/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>   //dont copy-paste this script
  <script type="text/javascript" src="menu bar/menu.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get that error is because you did not load the lavalamp script before calling the function. Use the example provided by klox and load the scripts in this order:

```
-jQuery
-lavalamp
-your initialisation code
```